# CSS3 rounded image corners not working in Safari/Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I've merrily hacking away at this website, testing it in Firefox and Internet Explorer 9, taking for granted that Safari and Chrome will render my CSS3 fine, when I've just discovered they don't.

In FF and IE9 I see this:

[image]

In Safari/Chrome I see this:

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img src="static/images/image1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
  .container {
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

**UPDATE**
Please see a working example of the problem I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/jAsnU/3 Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
.container img {
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'd love to know the specifics of why that worked, and why Webkit browsers didn't hide the overflow, but this was the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I recently had the same problem. And this was the only solution that worked for me. Why it worked? I assume its because webkit doesn't actually register the underlying parent elements roundedness to the children. If you had a child div, it might also need the roundedness as well. You could do that experiment and prove this to yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding "overflow:hidden;" to the style of the div. I made a quick test page up at jsfiddle and it seemed to work (tested it in Chrome, Safari and FireFox): http://jsfiddle.net/wabw8/

Comment: While your JS Fiddle works fine, it doesn't work when I try it on my project. Very annoying! I think it must have something to do with the fact that the images are actually being added later by javascript as part of a carousel (http://slidesjs.com/).

Comment: I'm not seeing where on that page border-radius is applied (unless you haven't moved it out to production yet).

Comment: I played around with it and noticed that it would flash the rounded corners after "Run" was pressed if you added "overflow:hidden" to the img,div tags. I'm wondering if the slides method is changing that property behind the scenes, however, I see the setting the border-radius for the img tag fixed things so I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try to set the border radius on .container div img.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Your answer worked, but ohmusama gave a better one.

Comment: yea, 4 people posted an answer to this question in under a minute! haha

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a `border`.

So, something like this:

`border:1px solid blue;`  //whatever blue you are using.

It looks as though FF and IE are giving you the rounded border... but as a blank item that is cutting off the image.